# Вывод постов wordpress через get_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

Натягиваю свою верстку на Wordpress, собственно пробую это селать впервые.

В примере кода я вывожу список постов через get_posts(). Каждый пост содержит слайдер `<ul class="splide__list">` , но в каждом слайдере может быть разное количество слайдов `<ul class="splide__list">`. Подскажите как в данном случае мне реализовать цикл с динамичеким выводом изображений, вне зависимости сколько их в каждом посте, 3, 4, или 5

```
 <?php
                            $my_posts = get_posts( array(
                                'numberposts' => -1,
                                'category_name'    => 'works',
                                'orderby'     => 'date',
                                'order'       => 'ASC',
                                'post_type'   => 'post',
                                'suppress_filters' => true, // подавление работы фильтров изменения SQL запроса
                            ) );

                            global $post;

                            foreach( $my_posts as $post ){
                                setup_postdata( $post );
                                ?>
                                
                                    <div class="work-card">
                                    <h2 class="work-card__title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                                    <div class="work-card__slider splide" id="work-slider">
                                        <div class="splide__track">
                                            <ul class="splide__list">
                                                <li class="splide__slide">
                                                    <img src="<?php the_field('image_1') ?>" alt="" class="work-card__img">
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="splide__slide">
                                                    <img src="<?php the_field('image_2') ?>" alt="" class="work-card__img">
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="splide__slide">
                                                    <img src="<?php the_field('image_3') ?>" alt="" class="work-card__img">
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="splide__slide">
                                                    <img src="<?php the_field('image_4') ?>" alt="" class="work-card__img">
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="splide__slide">
                                                    <img src="<?php the_field('image_5') ?>" alt="" class="work-card__img">
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="work-card__description">
                                        <?php the_field('category_descr') ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php
                            }

                            wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
                        ?>
```

Comment: Если используете плагин ACF, то там есть поле "группа". Так вот слайдер лучше делать через группу картинок, а не через отдельные картинки (раз у Вас их разное количество). Тогда в шаблоне Вы обходите эту группу циклом foreach, проверяете, есть ли картинка, и выводите её в слайдере.

Comment: Обычно это делается через Repeater или Gallery в ACF. Ну а так, отдельными полями, то не совсем понятно как много изображений там может быть, возьмите максимальный индекс (сколько у Вас там полей, 5?) и перебирайте циклом, с проверкой что изображение есть.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.

Comment: @Simon, Repeater и Gallery есть только в платной Pro версии. А группа есть в бесплатной.

Comment: @humster_spb да, но лично я не вижу никаких преимуществ у ACF Group с 5-тью подполями, над просто 5-тью полями.